# Can I modify a quantifier with “not”?

Tags: negation, quantifiers

> There’s a 2/3 apple.

1. There’s a not whole (=incomplete) apple.
2. There’s a not half apple.

Are these two sentences acceptable?

Comment: Hello,  You've asked an "apple" question.  This might be because you have a real problem in English, but you have simplified the situation and asked about apples instead of the real situation.  Be aware that the answers might only work for apples, and might not be useful for your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

They are borderline grammatical.  None of them are natural or idiomatic.

It is probably impossible to say what a native speaker would say in this context. The context is artificial.  A native speaker would not normally need to describe the existence of partial apples to another native speaker, in such a way as to indicate that there is part of an apple but that part is not half of an apple. However better would be:

> There's two thirds of an apple.

Not "a 2/3 apple."